# How to sample 25% of only successful traces using open telemetry collector(AWS ADOT collector)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector, opentelemetry-tail-sampling, aws-adot-collector

I have a use case where I want to `sample 25% of all successful trace` ( which does not have error)。

I have 2 more use cases:

- Sample all error traces ( no problem)
- Sample all High latency traces (no problem)

I am using ADOT collector. Upon reading the [README.md for tail sampling processor](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/processor/tailsamplingprocessor/README.md).

My understanding is that my use case can be achieved by using `and` policy.Like combination go two policies

- Sample only Error free successful traces
- Sample only 25% probabilistic traces

I tried the following policy but not luck

```
{
              name: send-percent-of-successful-traces,
              type: and,
              and:
                {
                  and_sub_policy:
                    [
                        {
                          name: only-200-response-code,
                          type: string_attribute,
                          string_attribute:
                            {
                                key: http.response.status,
                                values: ["200"],
                                enabled_regex_matching: true,
                            },
                        },
                        {
                          name: sample-percent-traces,
                          type: probabilistic,
                          probabilistic: { sampling_percentage: 25 },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            },
```

Is there any other way to achieve my use case?

**Note: I already have 2 more policies to sample only error traces and high latency traces so I cannot use another processor to filter 404 error traces.**

Comment: try status code 

      {
          name: test-policy-5,
          type: status_code,
          status_code: {status_codes: [OK]}
        } 

https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/blob/main/processor/tailsamplingprocessor/testdata/tail_sampling_config.yaml#L27-L29